# Suckling directly from a kosher animal

Tags: halacha, food, animals, dairy

After scouring the internet for various legitimate medical cures to a certain innocuous virus, several obscure websites suggest suckling directly from the teat of a goat (mirrored by several people my wife has recently spoken to…).

Discounting the medical aspect of this topic (or life threatening situation), are there any halachic issues regarding children and/or adults suckling directly from a kosher animal?

Comment: There is a special prohibition on suckling directly from a human lest one confuse human milk and other animals-whose-meat-you-cannot-eat's milk. So it seems aside from humans it should be ok.

Comment: @DoubleAA sounds like an answer (your proof is of a the same type as the proof in the existing answer, actually: we see a prohibition on a subcase for a specific reason, so it seems to be permissible in general). Why not post it as such?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We learn in Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 328:33 [סימן שכח - דין חולה בשבת](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_25.html#HtmpReportNum0086_L2):

> **לג** גּוֹנֵחַ, מֻתָּר  לִינֹק חָלָב מֵהַבְּהֵמָה, דְּבִמְקוֹם צַעְרָא לֹא גָּזְרוּ רַבָּנָן. וְיֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים שֶׁאִם אֵין לוֹ אֶלָּא צַעַר שֶׁל רָעָב, אָסוּר  לִינֹק מֵהַבְּהֵמָה בְּשַׁבָּת ‏

Somebody with [some kind of] heart issues may suckle directly from an animal on Shabbat [and there's no problem of מפרק, since the Rabbis did not make decrees in cases of pain. Some say that if the issue is hunger, then he may not suckle on Shabbat.

We see from here that if we're not dealing with Shabbat - suckling resembles מפרק (threshing) - **there seems to be no issue with suckling directly from an animal**.

(The [Yalkut Yosef 305:12](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01355_part_22.html#HtmpReportNum0065_L2) also forbids it on Yom Tov.)